# Do TVA employees get paid?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, loki-2021, time-variance-authority

I mean, they are employees, right? At least they believe they are, right? So they should have a salary, perhaps in the form of some TVA credits? They also should have endowment insurance and medical insurance, but don't need to pay taxes, perhaps? How do they use the TVA money?

Or are they never actually paid, but with memory reset once a payday is met?

Comment: "I mean, they are employees, right?" Are they? "At least they believe they are, right?" Do they? Did anyone from the TVA ever say that in the show?

Comment: What would they spend money on? They don't appear to leave the TVA except to go on missions, and there don't appear to be any shops at the TVA.

Comment: I seem to recall **free pie** being available (even if only one flavor) so one would assume that their basic needs are provided by the TVA. Their motivation would seem to be a belief in the TVA's mission. It's only when they learn that they have other options (on their original timelines) that their motivation wavers.

Comment: I don't understand the downvotes. This is a valid question, even if the answer is "no" (I wouldn't know). Instead of downvoting, just answer with why the answer is "no" and earn some upvotes :)

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Though it is not explicitly said in the show, we can speculate.  Work without pay is called slave labor. What would a slave do when he could go to any place at any time?

Comment: @Harry That isn't slave labor. That's unpaid labor, which is only unethical under systems like Capitalism. There are plenty of scenarios where unpaid labor isn't unethical, like volunteer work or in a civilization where monetary compensation has no value or use.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149762/discussion-on-question-by-harry-do-tva-employees-get-paid); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't believe the subject of TVA staff being paid money for their work has ever come up on the show, but the available evidence suggests it's unlikely.

Firstly, as far as we've been told, the TVA was founded by He Who Remains and exists in a region outside of the Sacred Timeline and time itself. Thus, it isn't tied to the economy of any existing country on Earth and wouldn't have its own money or banking services by default. There isn't any evidence to suggest that He Who Remains bothered to create such things, or any obvious reason why he'd wish to do so.

Secondly, He Who Remains apparently recruited his staff by plucking them from the Sacred Timeline or other timelines, wiping their memories, and indoctrinating them to believe that they were created by the Time-Keepers to carry out vital work, preserving the flow of time and preventing the onset of another multiversal war. As far as they knew, they didn't have lives, families or friends outside of the TVA, and weren't working for a conventional employer, but rather their own creators. So it wasn't so much a job in the usual sense, as something more akin to a religious vocation.

From what we've seen, TVA staff don't have access to goods or services within the TVA, outside of those supplied by the TVA itself, and there's nothing to suggest they're required to pay for those things. The only time we see TVA staff pay for anything is during missions on Earth; for example, Mobius buys a newspaper in 19th century Chicago in S02E03. We can't be sure where he got that money from, but my guess is that the TVA keeps some money from pruned timelines to use for expenses on missions. We know from S01E01 that they keep other things from pruned timelines, such as Infinity Stones.

It's since been revealed to the TVA staff that the Time-Keepers were just robotic puppets, and that their real master was He Who Remains, but it appears that most of them are still willing to carry out their work, ostensibly without pay, because it turns out that it is genuinely vital to the preservation of human existence and of reality in general.

Comment: They have free food from the Automat; https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QPulfsQ7zbw